# C#: Method fails when called from test method but works fine otherwise

Tags: c#, unit-testing, azure, azure-sql-database

I have method works fine when I call it from other places in the code, I added unit test to test this method and when it's being called from the test method it throws exception in the very first line.

```
    public static void PostToAzureQueue(AlertNotification alertNotification)
    {
        CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageConnectionString"));
        CloudQueueClient queueClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudQueueClient();
        CloudQueue queue = queueClient.GetQueueReference("activealertsqueue");
        queue.CreateIfNotExists();
        CloudQueueMessage message = new CloudQueueMessage(alertNotification.Serialize());
        queue.AddMessage(message);
    }
```

And here is the test method

```
    public void VerifyPostToAzureQueue()
    {
        try
        {
            AlertNotification alertNotification = new AlertNotification();
            alertNotification.DataCenters = "TestCenter";
            alertNotification.TimeStamp = DateTime.Now;
            Utils.PostToAzureQueue(alertNotification);

            Assert.IsTrue(true);
        }
        catch
        {
            Assert.Fail();
        }
    }
```

When I hard code the connection string in the first line in the method, it passed this line but failed in the 2nd line.
The method works just fine when I call it from anywhere else.
Please note that the test method is in separate test project.

Comment: All your test message is doing is checking if true == true. It's always going to pass. Whats the error?

Comment: What is the exception that you're seeing?

Comment: `try {...} catch { Assert.Fail(); }` is not a good test pattern.  Don't catch exceptions in the test, just let them bubble up and the testing framework will inform you the test failed because of an exception and will even give you the message and stack trace which are very useful.

Comment: I removed the try{} catch{} and here is the message I'm getting

Result Message: 
Test method SolutionName.Test.ClientErrorTests.VerifyPostToAzureQueue threw exception: 
System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: connectionString

Comment: Are you writing a Unit test or an Integration test? There is a very distinct difference between the 2 and 2 very different solutions to creating a test method depending on the answer.

Comment: Does AlertNotficiation contain a connectionString property? Look up what a null reference exception is that should help you.

Comment: I'm creating unit test not integration test.
The AlertNotification class doesn't contain connection string proberty, the connectionstring should be retrieved from the solution settings.

Comment: What is confusing me is I don't know what is the difference between calling the method from inside the project or from the test project, it should be the same method that executes the same code.

Comment: `I'm creating unit test not integration test.` => Then the answer is to Fake the Azure parts. There are various testing frameworks you can do that with like MS Fakes, NSubstitute, Moq, etc. The reason for the failure is that you are actually calling the real azure types that are trying to be instantiated with the actual connection string from a app/web config which should not happen, you should test **your code** and not the azure types.

Answer (score 5):

Based on your comments above, you are seeing a null reference exception because your code, probably this line:

```
CloudStorageAccount.Parse(CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageConnectionString"))
```

isn't able to find a connection string. As you noted, your test function is in a separate project from your production code, so the `StorageConnectionString` probably isn't in an accessible configuration file.

Which nicely demonstrates why it's a bad idea to build connection objects in your code where you're going to use it. Your current `PostToAzureQueue` method does multiple things:

1. It gets connection settings for your account.
2. It creates a client for your account.
3. It creates an `activealertsqueue` if it doesn't exist.
4. It sends a message to that queue.

This violates the [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle). This method should do one thing: send a message to a queue. You should refactor this method to do only that one thing, and then provide it with the tools that it needs to do that thing. So it would look something like:

```
public static void PostToAzureQueue(AlertNotification alertNotification, CloudQueueClient client)
{
    var queue = client.GetQueueReference("activealertsqueue");
    queue.AddMessage(new CloudQueueMessage(alertNotification.Serialize()));
}
```

Your client should be created externally and [injected](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) into your code (really it should be injected into the parent class and not this method, but that's a different discussion). You can then handle any exceptions (say, a `QueueNotExists` or whatever would be thrown if `activealertsqueue` doesn't exist) and retry logic where `PostToAzureQueue` is called. By extracting these pieces of functionality from this method you will simplify this method and make it more testable.